# need to stop rotation of camera overlay

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my `universal application`, I am creating a `camera overlay view` over my camera interface. Note that My app is locked for `portrait mode`. However, when I change the interface orientation of iPad, the overlay also rotates with it. But i don't want that!

How to stop it from rotating with rotation in interface?

this is how the overlay looks in portrait on **iPAD** (with home button down):

[image]

And this is how rotates in landscape on **iPAD** (with home button on left):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you disable all but Portrait orientations in your app settings.
[image]

**EDIT**

You can also create a custom `UIImagePickerController` class like this:

```
@interface MyImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation MyImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

Comment: yupp i have done that.. nothing rotates except the overlay.. Also, the  round button of the camera also changes its position. As you can see it in the sceenshot...

Comment: yupp.. i subclassed UIImagePickerController and then implemented the methods you said. However, I am cynical about subclassing it.. Apple strongly discourages that..

Comment: It also says that it supports portrait mode only, all you've done is enforce that (which they've failed to do).